# BLE Scanning Devices

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have this WinForms project which utilizes the [32feet](https://github.com/inthehand/32feet) library. The following code snippet is supposed to detect the BLE devices (Bluetooth Low Energy Devices) however, it returns the normal Bluetooth devices only.

Any idea?

```cs
private void blescan()
{
    {
        lsb_device.Items.Clear();
        BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Mode = RadioMode.Connectable;
        BluetoothClient client = new BluetoothClient();
        BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devices = client.DiscoverDevices();
        BluetoothClient bluetoothClient = new BluetoothClient();
        String authenticated;
        String classOfDevice;
        String connected;
        String deviceAddress;
        String deviceName;
        String installedServices;
        String lastSeen;
        String lastUsed;
        String remembered;
        String rssi;
        foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo device in devices)
        {
            lbl_status.Visible = true;
            authenticated = device.Authenticated.ToString();
            classOfDevice = device.ClassOfDevice.ToString();
            connected = device.Connected.ToString();
            deviceAddress = device.DeviceAddress.ToString();
            deviceName = device.DeviceName.ToString();
            installedServices = device.InstalledServices.ToString();
            lastSeen = device.LastSeen.ToString();
            lastUsed = device.LastUsed.ToString();
            remembered = device.Remembered.ToString();
            rssi = device.Rssi.ToString();
            string[] row = new string[] { authenticated, classOfDevice, connected, deviceAddress, deviceName, installedServices, lastSeen, lastUsed, remembered, rssi };

            lsb_device.Items.Add("Device Name:" + row[4] + " || MAC Address:" + row[3]);
        }
        lbl_status.Text = "Scan completed.";
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot for the scanning `Form`:

[image: BLE Scanner]

Comment: Use MAC address.  The MAC contains the Manufacturer, Model, Serial Number.  So lower power device will have different MAC than high power devices.